# After logging in on os X another login panel called "others" pops up

Tags: macos, mac

When this morning I opened my Mac I could not log in anymore: after I log in to my administrator account, another login interface shows up with "others" written below it.

Unfortunately I have no clue of what the password and id is, so I cannot log in to my Mac anymore.

This is the screenshot of the issue

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LJcjWEh.jpg]

Comment: Are you using FileVault? What does the initial login screen look like? Does it differ from the one above?

Comment: Yeah the first one is different its all grey on the background. No i dont have filevault

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but you may somehow have turned on the Root User.

Use Spotlight to find ‘Directory Utilitu.app

1. Double-click on Directory Utility.app to open it.
2. Click on the lock to authenticate.
3. Choose the Edit menu in the Menu Bar
4. If ‘Disable Root User’ is in the drop-down menu, click it.

If you see ‘Enable Root User’, this is not the problem.

Comment: Yes i did activare the root user some times ago, how do i disable it now? I cannot use the spotlight because i can't log in

Comment: @AlessandroSportelli Can you log in as root? This looks to me like something's wrong with your regular account, and logging in as root would at least let you look around to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget your admin password or are unable to enter it, you could create a new Admin account.

I do this all the time with Users who have forgotten their passwords.  It's basically removing the file that tells the OS that the first setup has been done, then starting the computer and going through the first setup again.  TIP:  Don't use the same name for the Admin account as you used originally, you only need a temporary Admin account to boot from in order to change the other Admin account passwords or to grab the data.

Boot  into Single User Mode (Command + s)

Check file system fsck(space)-fy

Mount(Space)-uw(Space)/

Remove the hidden ".AppleSetupDone" file.

rm(space)/var/db/.applesetupdone  (there is a . in front of apple)

type “reboot" and create a new Admin Account.